# Show success message on form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to have this form submitted and it works. However, i can't get to show a "success" message after clicking submit button.

```
    function signup() {
    var postData={ "service" :$('input[name=service]').val(), "ent_id": $('input[name=ent_id]').val(), "name": $('input[name=name]').val(), "mail_address" : $('input[name=mail_address]').val(), "password": $('input[name=password]').val()};
    postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://domain.com/api?service=security&action=signup&request=' + postData,
            type: 'GET',
            });
    return false;
            }
```

Here's the form:

```
    <form onsubmit="return signup()">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    Email:<input type="text" name="mail_address">
    Password:  <input type="password" name="password" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="service" value="wf" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ent_id" value="null" />
    </form>
```

Could someone here help me out with the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want it to do. All you need to do is use the success / error callbacks that come with jQuery.

```js
function signup() {
  var postData={
    "service": $('input[name=service]').val(),
    "ent_id": $('input[name=ent_id]').val(),
    "name": $('input[name=name]').val(),
    "mail_address" : $('input[name=mail_address]').val(),
    "password": $('input[name=password]').val()
  };
  postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/api?service=security&action=signup&request=' + postData,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() {
      alert('successfully submitted');
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('an error has occurred.');
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Weird but even though i'm getting email verification saying it's a success, it still shows "an error has occurred." Also, there's a delay and takes about 2 to 3 seconds :(

Can you fix it?

Comment: An error has occurred is being displayed because the status code that is returned is NOT in the 200 range. You might want to replace `error: function() { alert('an error has occurred.'); }` with `error: function(err) { console.log(err); }` and then view your browsers developer console to see what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("form[name='myForm']").submit(function(e) {
 var postData={ "service" :$('input[name=service]').val(), "ent_id": $('input[name=ent_id]').val(), "name": $('input[name=name]').val(), "mail_address" : $('input[name=mail_address]').val(), "password": $('input[name=password]').val()};
     postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
     $.ajax({
            url: 'http://domain.com/api?service=security&action=signup&request=' + postData,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data){
                  //alert(data);  
                  alert("success message");
                 }
            });
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: i added some changes.try this and let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: the URL now has the fields entered. The form which was working earlier stop working too. Thank You for the effort though.